# altering displayed web page

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, firefox, firefox-addon

I am attempting to write a firefox addon that will analyze the displayed page and change the text display to be hyper links (according to some algorithm).

I am trying to fogure out how can i parse the html document tree to retrieve the text in order to make it a link.
So i need not only the text but its position in the document.
Like if i had some kind of parser that will give me only text nodes or something, and then i can replace its content.

Is there such a thing at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert javascript into every page so you have everything that javascript can do. A good place to start learning about Firefox addon development is the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension

Comment: I read all the documentation already. And i setup firefox extension development environment. I am looking for some existing library to use. I dont want to invent basic html parsing all over.

Comment: ah ok. Should make that clear in your question. I believe what you need is xPath https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: Further, there is a fantastic Firefox / firebug addon called FirePath that allows you to test your xPath on the fly =] - If you decide that is your "chosen answer", I'll update it for future reference.

Comment: Don't see how xpath helps me. because i dont know the structure of the web page

Comment: You can use xpath like you might regex but it's less complicated. So you might for example extract all the content of all <p> tags. If you don't know the structure of the web page, you have to make a TON of assumptions. You could use xpath for exmaple to extract all <h1> tags or <h2> tags content etc.